# Java SSL Handshake problems with Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, ssl, https, apache-httpclient-4.x

I prepared the keystore again and now I am getting handshake problem.
Please find the trace as follows:

```
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=GeoTrust Global CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x23a6f
  Valid from Wed Nov 06 03:06:50 IST 2013 until Sat May 21 03:06:50 IST 2022

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GeoTrust Global CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=GeoTrust Global CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x23456
  Valid from Tue May 21 09:30:00 IST 2002 until Sat May 21 09:30:00 IST 2022

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=TEST-V3, OU=Payment Systems - Test, O=IBM
  Issuer:  CN=IBM Payment Systems Test Certification Authority, OU=IBM Payment Systems, O=IBM, C=DK
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1af
  Valid from Thu Mar 09 05:30:00 IST 2017 until Thu Aug 01 05:29:59 IST 2019

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Executing request GET https://test:50443/ping/sys HTTP/1.1
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring disabled protocol: SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1472397740 bytes = { 90, 142, 214, 84, 183, 215, 31, 160, 157, 197, 81, 89, 66, 174, 32, 173, 75, 155, 37, 76, 134, 0, 61, 180, 100, 107, 107, 127 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=test]
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 181
0000: 01 00 00 B1 03 01 58 C3   02 AC 5A 8E D6 54 B7 D7  ......X...Z..T..
0010: 1F A0 9D C5 51 59 42 AE   20 AD 4B 9B 25 4C 86 00  ....QYB. .K.%L..
0020: 3D B4 64 6B 6B 7F 00 00   2C C0 0A C0 14 00 35 C0  =.dkk...,.....5.
0030: 05 C0 0F 00 39 00 38 C0   09 C0 13 00 2F C0 04 C0  ....9.8...../...
0040: 0E 00 33 00 32 C0 08 C0   12 00 0A C0 03 C0 0D 00  ..3.2...........
0050: 16 00 13 00 FF 01 00 00   5C 00 0A 00 34 00 32 00  ........\...4.2.
0060: 17 00 01 00 03 00 13 00   15 00 06 00 07 00 09 00  ................
0070: 0A 00 18 00 0B 00 0C 00   19 00 0D 00 0E 00 0F 00  ................
0080: 10 00 11 00 02 00 12 00   04 00 05 00 14 00 08 00  ................
0090: 16 00 0B 00 02 01 00 00   00 00 1A 00 18 00 00 15  ................
00A0: 69 70 73 2D 70 72 65 70   72 6F 64 2E 69 68 6F 73  test
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 181
[Raw write]: length = 186
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 01 00 55                                     ....U
[Raw read]: length = 85
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 85
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: -1763120708 bytes = { 59, 4, 22, 253, 85, 2, 33, 55, 71, 167, 214, 2, 43, 34, 103, 36, 246, 211, 29, 98, 71, 35, 217, 149, 242, 147, 142, 60 }
Session ID:  {130, 248, 4, 146, 215, 60, 121, 119, 106, 192, 124, 239, 63, 133, 32, 255, 251, 76, 14, 153, 69, 208, 159, 189, 205, 94, 191, 243, 14, 21, 112, 15}
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Extension server_name, server_name: 
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
** TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 85
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 2375
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=test, O=IBM Danmark ApS, L=Ballerup, ST=Denmark, C=DK
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Wed Aug 19 05:30:00 IST 2015,
               To: Thu Oct 18 05:29:59 IST 2018]
  Issuer: CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  SerialNumber: [    58fc8755 d3dec7e7 4f9dd9a6 64d6c312]

Certificate Extensions: 8
[1]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: ocsp
   accessLocation: URIName: http://gn.symcd.com
, 
   accessMethod: caIssuers
   accessLocation: URIName: http://gn.symcb.com/gn.crt
]
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: D2 6F F7 96 F4 85 3F 72   3C 30 7D 23 DA 85 78 9B  .o....?r<0.#..x.
0010: A3 7C 5A 7C                                        ..Z.
]
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://gn.symcb.com/gn.crl]
]]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [2.23.140.1.2.2]

[6]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
  clientAuth
]

[7]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

[8]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: test
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:

]
chain [1] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 28750030505165604890850270805621306257072804387937490615824770523820321362550937780850035994683054588055508748696205117506674985865653625543463062925106222857728617711064416811840996536244297773530394755403023692961185980704471296075689618905841805280863747434432441027316024968573511986381257910569786560233452976395052435967005000570194527947098842065537915042318598723531518795601302291733897107118135130366085680274591705427460152216995720185506015185633329842959670187299414247347586421938382568908384120224025448454551141331962396420208135784878289124860435208739614728353739364385405169171116352649372320734821
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Wed Nov 06 03:06:50 IST 2013,
               To: Sat May 21 03:06:50 IST 2022]
  Issuer: CN=GeoTrust Global CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  SerialNumber: [    023a6f]

Certificate Extensions: 8
[1]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: ocsp
   accessLocation: URIName: http://g2.symcb.com
]
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: C0 7A 98 68 8D 89 FB AB   05 64 0C 11 7D AA 7D 65  .z.h.....d.....e
0010: B8 CA CC 4E                                        ...N
]
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:0
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://g1.symcb.com/crls/gtglobal.crl]
]]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [2.16.840.1.113733.1.7.54]
[PolicyQualifierInfo: [
  qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1
  qualifier: 0000: 16 25 68 74 74 70 3A 2F   2F 77 77 77 2E 67 65 6F  .%http://www.geo
0010: 74 72 75 73 74 2E 63 6F   6D 2F 72 65 73 6F 75 72  trust.com/resour
0020: 63 65 73 2F 63 70 73                               ces/cps

]]  ]
]

[6]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  Key_CertSign
  Crl_Sign
]

[7]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  CN=SymantecPKI-1-539
]

[8]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: D2 6F F7 96 F4 85 3F 72   3C 30 7D 23 DA 85 78 9B  .o....?r<0.#..x.
0010: A3 7C 5A 7C                                        ..Z.
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: A0 D4 F7 2C FB 74 0B 7F   64 F1 CD 43 6A 9F 62 53  ...,.t..d..Cj.bS
0010: 1C 02 7C 98 90 A2 EE 4F   68 D4 20 1A 73 12 3E 77  .......Oh. .s.>w
0020: B3 50 EB 72 BC EE 88 BE   7F 17 EA 77 8F 83 61 95  .P.r.......w..a.
0030: 4F 84 A1 CB 32 4F 6C 21   BE D2 69 96 7D 63 BD DC  O...2Ol!..i..c..
0040: 2B A8 1F D0 13 84 70 FE   F6 35 95 89 F9 A6 77 B0  +.....p..5....w.
0050: 46 C8 BB B7 13 F5 C9 60   69 D6 4C FE D2 8E EF D3  F......`i.L.....
0060: 60 C1 80 80 E1 E7 FB 8B   6F 21 79 4A E0 DC A9 1B  `.......o!yJ....
0070: C1 B7 FB C3 49 59 5C B5   77 07 44 D4 97 FC 49 00  ....IY\.w.D...I.
0080: 89 6F 06 4E 01 70 19 AC   2F 11 C0 E2 E6 0F 2F 86  .o.N.p../...../.
0090: 4B 8D 7B C3 B9 A7 2E F4   F1 AC 16 3E 39 49 51 9E  K..........>9IQ.
00A0: 17 4B 4F 10 3A 5B A5 A8   92 6F FD FA D6 0B 03 4D  .KO.:[...o.....M
00B0: 47 56 57 19 F3 CB 6B F5   F3 D6 CF B0 F5 F5 A3 11  GVW...k.........
00C0: D2 20 53 13 34 37 05 2C   43 5A 63 DF 8D 40 D6 85  . S.47.,CZc..@..
00D0: 1E 51 E9 51 17 1E 03 56   C9 F1 30 AD E7 9B 11 A2  .Q.Q...V..0.....
00E0: B9 D0 31 81 9B 68 B1 D9   E8 F3 E6 94 7E C7 AE 13  ..1..h..........
00F0: 2F 87 ED D0 25 B0 68 F9   DE 08 5A F3 29 CC D4 92  /...%.h...Z.)...

]
***
Found trusted certificate:
[
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 28750030505165604890850270805621306257072804387937490615824770523820321362550937780850035994683054588055508748696205117506674985865653625543463062925106222857728617711064416811840996536244297773530394755403023692961185980704471296075689618905841805280863747434432441027316024968573511986381257910569786560233452976395052435967005000570194527947098842065537915042318598723531518795601302291733897107118135130366085680274591705427460152216995720185506015185633329842959670187299414247347586421938382568908384120224025448454551141331962396420208135784878289124860435208739614728353739364385405169171116352649372320734821
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Wed Nov 06 03:06:50 IST 2013,
               To: Sat May 21 03:06:50 IST 2022]
  Issuer: CN=GeoTrust Global CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  SerialNumber: [    023a6f6   13 02 47 42 31 17 30 15  .0...U....GB1.0.
0020: 06 03 55 04 08 13 0E 43   61 6D 62 72 69 64 67 65  ..U....Cambridge
0030: 73 68 69 72 65 31 12 30   10 06 03 55 04 07 13 09  shire1.0...U....
0040: 43 61 6D 62 72 69 64 67   65 31 15 30 13 06 03 55  Cambridge1.0...U
0050: 04 0A 13 0C 57 6F 72 6C   64 50 61 79 20 4C 74 64  ....WorldPay Ltd
0060: 31 1F 30 1D 06 03 55 04   0B 13 16 41 70 70 6C 69  1.0...U....Appli
0070: 63 61 74 69 6F 6E 20 4D   61 6E 61 67 65 6D 65 6E  cation Managemen
0080: 74 31 1B 30 19 06 03 55   04 03 13 12 57 50 47 20  t1.0...U....WPG 
0090: 43 6C 69 65 6E 74 20 52   6F 6F 74 20 43 41 00 76  Client Root CA.v
00A0: 30 74 31 0B 30 09 06 03   55 04 06 13 02 44 4B 31  0t1.0...U....DK1
00B0: 0C 30 0A 06 03 55 04 0A   13 03 49 42 4D 31 1C 30  .0...U....IBM1.0
00C0: 1A 06 03 55 04 0B 13 13   49 42 4D 20 50 61 79 6D  ...U....IBM Paym
00D0: 65 6E 74 20 53 79 73 74   65 6D 73 31 39 30 37 06  ent Systems1907.
00E0: 03 55 04 03 13 30 49 42   4D 20 50 61 79 6D 65 6E  .U...0IBM Paymen
00F0: 74 20 53 79 73 74 65 6D   73 20 54 65 73 74 20 43  t Systems Test C
0100: 65 72 74 69 66 69 63 61   74 69 6F 6E 20 41 75 74  ertification Aut
0110: 68 6F 72 69 74 79 00 78   30 76 31 0B 30 09 06 03  hority.x0v1.0...
0120: 55 04 06 13 02 44 4B 31   0C 30 0A 06 03 55 04 0A  U....DK1.0...U..
0130: 13 03 49 42 4D 31 1D 30   1B 06 03 55 04 0B 13 14  ..IBM1.0...U....
0140: 49 42 4D 20 50 61 79 6D   65 6E 74 73 20 47 61 74  IBM Payments Gat
0150: 65 77 61 79 31 3A 30 38   06 03 55 04 03 13 31 49  eway1:08..U...1I
0160: 42 4D 20 50 61 79 6D 65   6E 74 73 20 47 61 74 65  BM Payments Gate
0170: 77 61 79 20 54 65 73 74   20 43 65 72 74 69 66 69  way Test Certifi
0180: 63 61 74 69 6F 6E 20 41   75 74 68 6F 72 69 74 79  cation Authority
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 01 00 04                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 4
0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 4
*** ServerHelloDone
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4
0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 269
0000: 0B 00 00 03 00 00 00 10   00 01 02 01 00 5B 8C E0  .............[..
0010: 1F 11 FA 1A 21 5E 38 87   25 C0 AF 7F D6 C3 A3 4E  ....!^8.%......N
0020: 65 D8 D2 34 FF 98 66 8F   57 78 81 C0 4B 80 A8 13  e..4..f.Wx..K...
0030: 4E 47 C3 33 CB 7F D1 58   94 A5 E0 D1 47 A6 E7 71  NG.3...X....G..q
0040: 3A 27 49 99 9B C0 5D 10   67 71 3F BA 3F 73 15 60  :'I...].gq?.?s.`
0050: 34 90 BC 7E 6D 52 33 8F   46 D4 0A BC 38 E9 9F 9B  4...mR3.F...8...
0060: ED 36 CC 84 91 ED E5 CB   31 A2 22 B5 A7 BF 22 A8  .6......1."...".
0070: B8 F3 A6 DA A5 CA CC BF   FB B5 E0 FA F7 E6 15 70  ...............p
0080: 40 C2 68 1C F8 C6 6D 2D   02 7E 00 9E 9F 54 2A 6F  @.h...m-.....T*o
0090: 4C 34 6A 40 F9 51 04 BA   50 2B 5F 9F 9D 04 B3 BA  L4j@.Q..P+_.....
00A0: 9D AE AB E2 0D 56 42 C0   3E 9A 2E C2 07 74 A4 86  .....VB.>....t..
00B0: 8B B9 B2 E9 C1 67 59 06   2E 0F 46 BC E9 37 ED 36  .....gY...F..7.6
00C0: 7B 71 8C 62 CD 29 ED 17   0D 3C 02 19 58 FF E8 B2  .q.b.)...<..X...
00D0: C7 D4 31 CC 54 BB 7C 5F   54 EB 8D 1B FE 0D E0 44  ..1.T.._T......D
00E0: 00 83 05 9C 46 28 06 93   5E FA A8 EF A8 6C EB B4  ....F(..^....l..
00F0: F0 4D 32 AD D8 90 7D 7F   8B 01 EC 47 2F 5C AC C9  .M2........G/\..
0100: 74 CD BC B1 27 74 83 15   FA 92 86 39 EC           t...'t.....9.
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 269
[Raw write]: length = 274
0000: 16 03 01 01 0D 0B 00 00   03 00 00 00 10 00 01 02  ................
0010: 01 00 5B 8C E0 1F 11 FA   1A 21 5E 38 87 25 C0 AF  ..[......!^8.%..
0020: 7F D6 C3 A3 4E 65 D8 D2   34 FF 98 66 8F 57 78 81  ....Ne..4..f.Wx.
0030: C0 4B 80 A8 13 4E 47 C3   33 CB 7F D1 58 94 A5 E0  .K...NG.3...X...
0040: D1 47 A6 E7 71 3A 27 49   99 9B C0 5D 10 67 71 3F  .G..q:'I...].gq?
0050: BA 3F 73 15 60 34 90 BC   7E 6D 52 33 8F 46 D4 0A  .?s.`4...mR3.F..
0060: BC 38 E9 9F 9B ED 36 CC   84 91 ED E5 CB 31 A2 22  .8....6......1."
0070: B5 A7 BF 22 A8 B8 F3 A6   DA A5 CA CC BF FB B5 E0  ..."............
0080: FA F7 E6 15 70 40 C2 68   1C F8 C6 6D 2D 02 7E 00  ....p@.h...m-...
0090: 9E 9F 54 2A 6F 4C 34 6A   40 F9 51 04 BA 50 2B 5F  ..T*oL4j@.Q..P+_
00A0: 9F 9D 04 B3 BA 9D AE AB   E2 0D 56 42 C0 3E 9A 2E  ..........VB.>..
00B0: C2 07 74 A4 86 8B B9 B2   E9 C1 67 59 06 2E 0F 46  ..t.......gY...F
00C0: BC E9 37 ED 36 7B 71 8C   62 CD 29 ED 17 0D 3C 02  ..7.6.q.b.)...<.
00D0: 19 58 FF E8 B2 C7 D4 31   CC 54 BB 7C 5F 54 EB 8D  .X.....1.T.._T..
00E0: 1B FE 0D E0 44 00 83 05   9C 46 28 06 93 5E FA A8  ....D....F(..^..
00F0: EF A8 6C EB B4 F0 4D 32   AD D8 90 7D 7F 8B 01 EC  ..l...M2........
0100: 47 2F 5C AC C9 74 CD BC   B1 27 74 83 15 FA 92 86  G/\..t...'t.....
0110: 39 EC                                              9.
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: 03 01 E2 E9 39 8F 1B E2   C5 2D 87 6C EC 06 B9 F1  ....9....-.l....
0010: DE A4 46 39 5A 29 75 42   17 C9 A6 D0 C8 66 A0 43  ..F9Z)uB.....f.C
0020: CA BE AF 3C E8 4A AF 67   E8 E1 CC 1B DA 37 4E E1  ...<.J.g.....7N.
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 58 C3 02 AC 5A 8E D6 54   B7 D7 1F A0 9D C5 51 59  X...Z..T......QY
0010: 42 AE 20 AD 4B 9B 25 4C   86 00 3D B4 64 6B 6B 7F  B. .K.%L..=.dkk.
Server Nonce:
0000: 97 E9 EA BC 3B 04 16 FD   55 02 21 37 47 A7 D6 02  ....;...U.!7G...
0010: 2B 22 67 24 F6 D3 1D 62   47 23 D9 95 F2 93 8E 3C  +"g$...bG#.....<
Master Secret:
0000: F8 ED 09 5D C9 9A 75 5F   64 93 B2 1F AF 1B AF 7B  ...]..u_d.......
0010: FF 46 26 15 53 36 AA 07   86 37 32 C6 A8 69 0E F1  .F&.S6...72..i..
0020: 22 23 57 ED B0 11 8F 43   B2 37 61 13 C6 93 CB 35  "#W....C.7a....5
Client MAC write Secret:
0000: D0 E7 74 D8 BF E0 EC 3B   A6 05 4A FB 8A 08 2E F5  ..t....;..J.....
0010: 03 18 AF 84                                        ....
Server MAC write Secret:
0000: BF F3 47 87 5B 12 EB 8A   CD CD C1 15 E8 0C 3A 7C  ..G.[.........:.
0010: 8F AF A0 62                                        ...b
Client write key:
0000: 21 C2 0E 03 A1 E5 64 BE   D6 D5 82 92 43 12 C4 2F  !.....d.....C../
Server write key:
0000: 3C 28 7D 04 5D E4 21 83   5D B9 97 C7 18 B0 34 A6  <(..].!.].....4.
Client write IV:
0000: 29 19 60 A2 AA 1C 12 8E   6D 2A 52 FF 27 5F 62 F6  ).`.....m*R.'_b.
Server write IV:
0000: 1F 08 C3 16 DA 35 1B 5F   9A 2A 61 89 BA 52 2D 55  .....5._.*a..R-U
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
[Raw write]: length = 6
0000: 14 03 01 00 01 01                                  ......
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 188, 233, 16, 38, 60, 75, 65, 122, 43, 133, 174, 190 }
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C BC E9 10 26   3C 4B 41 7A 2B 85 AE BE  .......&<KAz+...
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 48
0000: 14 00 00 0C BC E9 10 26   3C 4B 41 7A 2B 85 AE BE  .......&<KAz+...
0010: AE 44 07 6D D0 13 3D B5   CA 45 64 E4 4A 7C 29 FB  .D.m..=..Ed.J.).
0020: 13 AE D5 33 0B 0B 0B 0B   0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B  ...3............
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
[Raw write]: length = 53
0000: 16 03 01 00 30 29 57 15   15 A7 F7 90 C4 4C AA DC  ....0)W......L..
0010: 99 5E 39 00 6A 38 72 A0   2F 71 90 68 A8 EF 34 C1  .^9.j8r./q.h..4.
0020: 9E 0D 1A EB CF 5A 9B 98   8E 3D 53 80 FD 89 64 F7  .....Z...=S...d.
0030: CB D7 BB 3B BC                                     ...;.
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 01 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28                                              .(
main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at com.husqvarna.poc.ClientCustomSSL.main(ClientCustomSSL.java:40)
```

When I checked the connection using "**openssl s_client -connect test**" command, I get the following info:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust SSL CA - G3
verify return:1
depth=0 C = DK, ST = Denmark, L = Ballerup, O = IBM Danmark ApS, CN = test
verify return:1
4294956672:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1493:SSL alert number 40
4294956672:error:140790E5:SSL routines:ssl23_write:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=DK/ST=Denmark/L=Ballerup/O=IBM Danmark ApS/CN=test
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3
 1 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=DK/ST=Denmark/L=Ballerup/O=IBM Danmark ApS/CN=test
issuer=/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3
---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
/C=GB/ST=Cambridgeshire/L=Cambridge/O=WorldPay Ltd/OU=Application Management/CN=WPG Client Root CA
/C=DK/O=IBM/OU=IBM Payment Systems/CN=IBM Payment Systems Test Certification Authority
/C=DK/O=IBM/OU=IBM Payments Gateway/CN=IBM Payments Gateway Test Certification Authority
Client Certificate Types: RSA sign, DSA sign, ECDSA sign
Requested Signature Algorithms: RSA+SHA256:DSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:DSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:DSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1:ECDSA+SHA1
Shared Requested Signature Algorithms: RSA+SHA256:DSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:DSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:DSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1:ECDSA+SHA1
---
SSL handshake has read 2913 bytes and written 354 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES128-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: EA40AC1BBF05A17FD208C14A274D4806A27EAFF63A9DA052F796E76BF6DD9817
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 72440DCEB2FDC82B000671D8AF54D6E4BBF6C635CB97F440E3DCE7530C4B52BB687A33FC134F65E10235109163C8F848
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1489175050
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Comment: `D:/Users/keystore.jks` or `D:/Users/user/Desktop/POC/p12/keystore.jks` which one is it? Also, are you sure that you have added the correct certificate to the trust store?

Comment: I just modified the path in code.. It's D:/Users/keystore.jks on both sides.. Yes the certificate is added correctly I suppose: Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

ipgkey, Mar 10, 2017, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 8D:8F:2E:78:D1:1C:A8:8B:3D:49:B1:6E:C3:41:59:C0:1E:BE:1E:08

Comment: What do you mean by 'on both sides'? Whatever is in `keystore` on the server side should be imported into client's  `truststore`, also if you don't use client authentication then your client probably don't need its own  'keystore' (not that this is a problem).  I assume that you are providing us with client side code and settings, but you change these settings from inside your code to read from another 'truststore'...   are these files identical? do they both contain server's certificates?

Comment: Both files are same and I edit the post with the correct path now and Yes it has certificate in it

Comment: Server certificate issued for `ips-preprod.ihost.com` so it valid only for domen name `ips-preprod.ihost.com`. If you connect to `test` your test server should be configured with certificate issued for CN=test

Comment: I have updated my query now with all the necessary fields causing handshake problem